# Securing web api2 with storing username password in sql server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-web-api2

I need to implement secure WebApi2, having token based authentication. However, the username and password should be stored in SQL server database.

Found an article "http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api". It appears that this is mainly using Azure services, any idea on how to change this to use SQL Server?

I tried updating web.config with the actual connection string however that gives 500 - Internal server error.

Comment: The best way to do what you want, is using the ThinkTecture IdentityServer3. I have implemented it in my Web Api 2 project and it works like a charm!

Comment: Is it replacement of Owin? and so Owin won't work with SQL server?

Comment: Nope. It uses OWIN as well, just makes it easier and provides a lot of different possibilities, one of them is using identity database to store all user & password, etc. Also, your project will be self standing and you won't depend on Azure or anything else.

Comment: I tried but it does not seems to be that easy :(. Would you please share some code/example/article around it?

Comment: yes it has some learning curve, but to get a starting point go here: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples
and download the samples. Within the samples, grab the "AspNetIdentity" one and play around with it. It should immediately give you the server side part of it (issuing tokens, storing users in database, etc.) Use a tool like Fiddler to send requests and get a grasp of it. Then you can develop the client side using any framework to interact with it, my preference is angularjs and if you get the server part under control I can also help you with the client side :)